# Applying search terms only to specific fields in the iTunes search API. Possible?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, itunes-search-api

Using the iTunes search api for app search, is it possible to pre-filter the results, so that the search terms get applied to a specific set of fields? For instance, the title. I am sick and tired of not finding anything, just because it is buried within the results, and some other more popular, but completely irrelevant app appears on top.

Answer (score 0):

The iTunes Search API does provide this feature, the documentation is pretty clear on how to do this.

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Look at the list of parameters you can append, the parameter you are looking for is "attribute":

> The attribute you want to search for in the stores, relative to the specified media type. For example, if you want to search for an artist by name specify entity=allArtist&attribute=allArtistTerm.
>
> In this example, if you search for term=maroon, iTunes returns "Maroon 5" in the search results, instead of all artists who have ever recorded a song with the word "maroon" in the title.
>
> The default is all attributes associated with the specified media type.

Comment: This once again does not apply to apps, because there is only one possible attribute

Comment: The "attribute" field for apps can narrow down your search term to target just the Developer field rather than everything the store knows about the apps.

Take for instance the following search for the term "Twitter":
http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=twitter&entity=software&attribute=softwareDeveloper

We only see six results because we narrowed down the scope of the search to only the Developer name.

The following search will find "Twitter" anywhere in the apps meta data:
http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=twitter&entity=software

Comment: which does not make much sense, does it, because in many cases, developer names have nothing to do with app names

Comment: I suppose it depends on the use case - if you know a developer that you would like to see all the games they have developed (say a developer with many games i.e. Big Fish Games), it makes sense to request as many as possible back from the API.  Now you can use your own search terms to filter on the results from this developer rather than using the search term against the entire catalog.  http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=big+fish+games&entity=software&attribute=softwareDeveloper&limit=300